# What causes Error 70 in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code which keeps causing an

```
Error 70: Permission Denied
```

in my VBA code.  I can't work out why, because I know that the worksheet is unprotected and that I can make changes to it.  The code in question is

```
sh.Name = "square"
```

It attempts to rename a shape that has been copied from another sheet and pasted into the sheet - there are no other shapes in the sheet with that name, because prior to these code I have already deleted all shapes with that name.

Any suggestion as to what might cause this permissions error?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code? How do you define the sh object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally that one is caused by trying to use the same name twice. Try doing this instead:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim lngIndx As Long
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim shp As Excel.Shape
    Set ws = Excel.ActiveSheet
    Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 174#, 94.5, 207#, 191.25)
    If NameUsed(ws, "Foo") Then
        lngIndx = 2
        Do While NameUsed(ws, "Foo" & CStr(lngIndx))
            lngIndx = lngIndx + 1
        Loop
        shp.name = "Foo" & CStr(lngIndx)
    Else
        shp.name = "Foo"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function NameUsed(ByVal parent As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal name As String) As Boolean
    Dim shp As Excel.Shape
    Dim blnRtnVal As Boolean
    name = LCase$(name)
    For Each shp In parent.Shapes
        If LCase$(shp.name) = name Then
            blnRtnVal = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    NameUsed = blnRtnVal
End Function
```

Comment: That helped - I used your NameUsed function (with a couple modifications) and discovered that the other shape with that name doesn't always get deleted (sometimes an error occurs when I try to call sh.Cut on that shape)

Comment: Does that answer your question then?

Comment: Yeah, that explains why I couldn't rename the shapes - thanks.

Comment: ooh! nice function. Thanks @Oorang cheers :D I had something similiar but forgot to add the .ToLower (LCase in VBA).

Answer (score 3):

Clean as you go. Set objects to nothing, strings to nullstring after using them and don't use the same names between functions and subroutines.

Answer (score 0):

"Permission Denied" is not for a protected worksheet but for wrong access to a property or variable.

I believe that "sh" is null at the point you are trying to access it and set its "Name" property. try to see if you initialized it correctly before setting its properties.

Comment: Checked this, and sh is definitely a valid shape

Answer (score 0):

There are several answers here on StackOverflow about this VB Error. Each answer or situation is unique in reality - although each existing answer states a different potential root cause (file permissions, folder permissions, name reuse, ranges, etc).

I would recommend narrowing down the root-cause by double clicking on the side of the stating function/code in order to mark a breakpoinnt (looks like a red dot) (Alternatively, you can right click on the line of the code - Select the `Toggle` and then `Breakpoint`).

Next, run your code, and it will stop in your breakpoint. You can then Step-Into/Over/Out your code and essentially find the line of code that is responsible for throwing your error code. (Step Into is `F8`, Step over is `Shift+F8` ((Go To the `Debug` top menu to see more options)))

Once you identified the responsible line of code - you can start looking further.

In my case scenario, I was using a protected variable name "Date" (look into [variable names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/index)). Once I renamed it to something else, the problem was fixed.