# fill list box with the data entered in text box

Tags: excel, vba

I have created one userform with multiple text boxes and combo boxes in it.
i have one list box also with 5 columns in it.
what i need is when i press the save button, the data entered in the text boxes and combo boxes is shown in list box and then clear the text box and combo box for another entry.

FOR SINGLE ENTRY IT IS WORKING BUT UNABLE TO ADD THE DATA IN THE NEW ROW.

HERE IS MY CODE:

> Blockquote

```
Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 5
Me.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "60;35;70;50"
Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.TextBox1.Text
Me.ListBox1.List(0, 1) = Me.ComboBox1.Value
Me.ListBox1.List(0, 2) = Me.ComboBox3.Value
Me.ListBox1.List(0, 3) = Me.TextBox5.Value
Me.ListBox1.List(0, 4) = Me.TextBox6.Value
```

attached is the image of my userform for your understanding.

kINDLY REVIEW AND ADVISE HOW TO OVERCOME THIS.

THANKS.
SALMAN KHAN

Answer (score 0):

May be something like the following (assuming you have one Textbox, and is named `TextBox1`, and your ListBox is named `ListBox1`, and your Save button is named `CommandButton1`):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    A = TextBox1.Text
    ListBox1.List = Array(A, "", "", " ", "")
    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Modify and complete according to your needs.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948950/what-causes-error-70-in-excel-vba) as a possible cause.