# Excel VBA Error - Runtime Error 70: Permission Denied

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with a code that was written for me. The code is below. I works find perhaps 70% of the time, but every approx 20 rows it throws up

> Runtime Error 70: Permission Denied

What would cause this, and is there any fix for it? Also, How can I change the code to skip any errors like this (or similar) and just move onto the next row.

Debugger throws up the line:   `If btn.ID = "gs_hdr_tsb" Then`

The full script is below.

```
Dim ie As Object
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate TextBox1.Text
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readystate = 4
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim prfl As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim INPTTG, btn As Object
    Dim Profile_link As String
    Dim H3tg As Object
    Dim iedata As Object
    If iedata Is Nothing Then
        Set iedata = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    End If
    iedata.Visible = True
    For i = TextBox2.Text To TextBox3.Text
        prfl = ws.Range("E" & i).Value
        For Each INPTTG In ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")
            If INPTTG.classname = "gs_in_txt" Then
                INPTTG.Value = ""
                INPTTG.Value = prfl
                Exit For
            End If
        Next INPTTG
        'button
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        For Each btn In ie.document.getelementsbytagname("button")
            If btn.ID = "gs_hdr_tsb" Then
                btn.Click
                Do
                DoEvents
                Loop Until ie.readystate = 4
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
            End If
        Next btn
        'prfl
        For Each H3tg In ie.document.getelementsbytagname("h3")
            If H3tg.classname = "gsc_oai_name" And VBA.Trim(H3tg.innertext) = prfl Then
                Call GetData(H3tg.getelementsbytagname("a").Item(0).href, iedata, i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next H3tg
        TextBox2.Text = i
    Next i
    MsgBox "Completed"
    iedata.Quit
    Set iedata = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save


End Sub
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You should never just "skip errors" - find the issue and do a check for it before execution.

Comment: maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948950/what-causes-error-70-in-excel-vba

Comment: it is possible that the web server is blocking your program because it is technically a web bot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
Dim ie As Object
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On error go to ErrMsg
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate TextBox1.Text
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readystate = 4
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
ErrMsg:
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim prfl As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim INPTTG, btn As Object
Dim Profile_link As String
Dim H3tg As Object
Dim iedata As Object
On error go to msgErr
If iedata Is Nothing Then
    Set iedata = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
End If
iedata.Visible = True
For i = TextBox2.Text To TextBox3.Text
    prfl = ws.Range("E" & i).Value
    For Each INPTTG In ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")
        If INPTTG.classname = "gs_in_txt" Then
            INPTTG.Value = ""
            INPTTG.Value = prfl
            Exit For
        End If
    Next INPTTG
    'button
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    For Each btn In ie.document.getelementsbytagname("button")
        If btn.ID = "gs_hdr_tsb" Then
            btn.Click
            Do
            DoEvents
            Loop Until ie.readystate = 4
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        End If
    Next btn
    'prfl
    For Each H3tg In ie.document.getelementsbytagname("h3")
        If H3tg.classname = "gsc_oai_name" And VBA.Trim(H3tg.innertext) = prfl Then
        Call GetData(H3tg.getelementsbytagname("a").Item(0).href, iedata, i)
        Exit For
        End If
    Next H3tg
    TextBox2.Text = i
Next i
MsgBox "Completed"
iedata.Quit
Set iedata = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
MsgErr:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several answers here on StackOverflow about this VB Error. Each answer or situation is unique in reality - although each existing answer states a different potential root cause (file permissions, folder permissions, name reuse, ranges, etc).

I would recommend narrowing down the root-cause by double clicking on the side of the stating function/code in order to mark a breakpoinnt (looks like a red dot) (Alternatively, you can right click on the line of the code - Select the `Toggle` and then `Breakpoint`).

Next, run your code, and it will stop in your breakpoint. You can then Step-Into/Over/Out your code and essentially find the line of code that is responsible for throwing your error code. (Step Into is `F8`, Step over is `Shift+F8` ((Go To the `Debug` top menu to see more options)))

Once you identified the responsible line of code - you can start looking further.

In my case scenario, I was using a protected variable name "Date" (look into [variable names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/index)). Once I renamed it to something else, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of this error (as was my case) is an antivirus/antimalware program blocking certain libraries.  Try temporarily disabling all antivirus/antimalware programs and test your script again.  In my case, Malwarebytes

In MalWare bytes, you can disable this setting by going to:

Security > Advanced Settings > Application Hardening [tab]

On the row called "Disable Loading of VBScript Libraries", un-check the checkbox under "MS Office".